# different ways to create a new instance of a class?

Tags: java, class, oop, instance

I know there are a bunch of different ways to create an `instance` of a `class`, which I don't know many of, But I've just seen this kind of definition.
I'm not even sure if it's making a new `instance`!!
Little misunderstanding and I can't digest it well.

Could anyone explain the code below?

```
new timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
          @Override
        public void run() {
            ...
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

Is there any difference between the one above and the one below? As long as they're the same, which one do you prefer?

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
          @Override
        public void run() {
            ...
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect the first to compile, unless `timer()` is a constructor, in which case the two are the same.

Comment: If I'm going to use a variable more than once, I create variable with `Timer t = new Timer()`, otherwise `new Timer()` is enough

Comment: The only difference (apart from the compilation error) is that in the first example you don't have a `timer` variable to refer to the `Timer` object later in the code; e.g. if you needed to call `timer.cancel()` later on for some reason.  Assuming that you don't, the the first form is (IMO) better.

Comment: They are different but in fact both are wrong. I wouldn't rely on the `Timer` continuing to operate after it has been garbage-collected, and you will certainly need some way to stop it some time, so you need to kee a reference to it, and not just in a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any different with this one? As long as there are same,
>   which one do you prefer?

Firsly, I'd like to point out what @Carcigenicate has said within the comments.

> "  I wouldn't expect the first to compile, unless timer() is a
>   constructor, in which case the two are the same."

I would assume that was a mistake and you meant to write `Timer()` as a constructor invocation.

The code below creates an anonymous object of type `Timer` and this is good to use when you want to perform a certain task there and then but don't expect to use the `Timer` object again. Basically, **you won't be able to reuse the object again later on in your code**.

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ...
            }
     }, 0, 1000);
```

The code below is equivalent to the one above except this one is not an anonymous `object` and **we can reuse the `object` later on in our code.**

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ...
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

> As long as they're the same, which one do you prefer?

It really depends on the circumstances and the situation but if i were to chose I'd go with the second one, for the reasons I have stated above.

Comment: Thank you, and just for clarify; **Yes, Timer () is a constructor.**